# Is the default theme from the Windows 7 beta available for use in the RTM version?

Tags: windows-7, themes

I really liked the default theme that shipped with Windows 7 beta, but it wasn't present in the RC build and doesn't appear to be available in the RTM version.

The theme I'm interested in is the "landscape" theme shown here:
http://lifehacker.com/5131371/windows-7-betas-many-free-and-legit-themes

Does anyone know if it's available for download anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the beta wallpapers - including the wheat field one -  from [www.intowindows.com/download-windows-7-beta-wallpaper-pack](http://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-7-beta-wallpaper-pack/) (I *assume* it's kosher to do this?)

My current fave is the 'Horizon' wallpaper from the new [OS X Snow Leopard wallpaper pack](http://uneasysilence.com/archive/2009/07/14293/).